# Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 when installing 'geopandas'

Tags: python, geopandas

Having troubles installing geopandas into python using "pip install geopandas" which is returning "Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 when installing..." error.

I am using python 2.7.14.

Comment: Can you give more details, like the full output of `pip install geopandas` ? Maybe try to make it verbose with `pip install geopandas --verbose`

Comment: Also make sure to update both `pip` and `setuptools` and then try again, an old version of those can also cause this.